# Is this a reliable way of counting occurrences with preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex

I need to **count the occurrences** of these characters (most of them must be escaped) in a given string:

```
[ // to be escaped
\ // to be escaped
] // to be escaped
^ // to be escaped
{ // to be escaped
| // to be escaped
} // to be escaped
~
€
```

So i ended up with **this pattern**: `'/[\[|\]|€\{|}|\\|\^|\||~]/u'`, hoping it's right (unfortunately i'm not so good in regex, need to study much more). Anyway, the result of:

```
$arr    = array();
$string = 't€s||t] st^_^ring[}}';
preg_match_all('/[\[|\]|€\{|}|\\|\^|\||~]/u', $string, $arr);
```

is kinda this:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '€' (length=3)
      1 => string '|' (length=1)
      2 => string '|' (length=1)
      3 => string ']' (length=1)
      4 => string '^' (length=1)
      5 => string '^' (length=1)
      6 => string '[' (length=1)
      7 => string '}' (length=1)
      8 => string '}' (length=1)
```

And i don't know how to interpret it. Can i simply `count($result[0])`? Is there a more reliable way?

Comment: `count($result[0])` should do just fine. Don't see why it wouldn't be reliable.

Comment: @RickKuipers What's the `0` index? I'm asking because don't know if i can rely upon that index.

Comment: do u want to count each, or just all together?

Comment: @helle altogether, it doesn't matter how many occurrences - say of euro symbol - there are.

Comment: ok, than I say the same as Rick does

Comment: Actually, after trying your code all I got was `bool(false)`...

Comment: @RickKuipers actually it works, but i can't match `€` symbol and `^`. Can't find why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), the return value for `preg_match_all` is an integer representing the number of full pattern matches, or a boolean **false** on error.

Comment: Indeed, the code does not seem to make sense, what is the array you are outputting?

Comment: Oh, thanks. The code has i typo i've fixed right now, didn't know i can use the returned value. Guess this is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried count_chars() instead? It give you stats on all the characters used in a string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php

Comment: My guess is that it is faster (CPU-wise) than using regex, yes. But the fastest solution (counting programming time) is probably the one that works, and since you original solution doesn't work right now I'd say that it's pretty slow. ;)

Comment: It depends on the data really but it's usually faster than regexps. It doesn't work in UTF-8 though. Either way, the difference in terms of performance is too small to make it a factor here.

Comment: @Janek i need UTF8 so count_chars() can't help, but thanks. Don't know why my regex doesn't work for you. It works for me even if can't match euro symbol and ^ symbol. Investigating why...

Comment: Ok, I see. Two more tips for you: use www.regexr.com to debug your regular expression, or use substr_count() in a loop to count the interesting chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily escape them like this:

```
preg_replace("/([\[\]\\\^\{\}\|\~\€])/", "\\$1", $string);
```

(If that's the end result you're after)